# Slice of Redux state returning undefined, initial state not working in mapStateToProps

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am trying to simply sort on the redux store data in `mapStateToProps`, similar to how it is being done in Dan Abramov's Egghead.io video: https://egghead.io/lessons/javascript-redux-colocating-selectors-with-reducers

My problem is, initially the state is returning undefined (as it is fetched asynchronously), so what would be the best way to deal with this? Current code is as follows (`_` is the `ramda` library):

```
const diff = (a, b) => {
  if (a.name < b.name) {
    return -1
  }
  if (a.name > b.name) {
    return 1
  }
  return 0
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    transactions: _.sort(diff, state.transactions.all),
    expenditure: state.expenditure.all,
    income: state.income.all
  }
}
```

I thought that `transactions.all` should initially be an empty array (which would mean the code would work) because of the initial state set in the reducer:

```
const INITIAL_STATE = { transactions: { all: [] }, transaction: null }

export default function (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case FETCH_TRANSACTION:
      return { ...state, transaction: action.payload.data }
    case FETCH_TRANSACTIONS:
      return { ...state, all: action.payload.data }
    case EDIT_TRANSACTION:
      return { data: action.data }
    case ADD_TRANSACTION:
      return { data: action.data }
    case DELETE_TRANSACTION:
      return { ...state }
    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not sure, but INITIAL_STATE have no `transations` key, so shouldn't it be `_.sort(diff, state.all)` ?

Comment: Hmm yes... there is an all for other reducers too, so maybe i need to be more explicit for each: defaultState = { transactions: { all: []}, expenditure: { all: [] }}; Thank you, I will try this

Answer (score 1):

As you said, it is fetched asynchronously. Perhaps when the component rendered, data isn't ready yet which resulted to an undefined object.

```
const SampleComponent = (props) => {
   if(props.transaction === undefined)
     return <Spinner /> // Loading state
   else 
     // your implementation
}
```

You can further make the code cleaner as explained by Dan himself in the docs here: http://redux.js.org/docs/advanced/AsyncActions.html

Comment: Thanks pierreg, but the default state  in the reducer initialises the .all to an empty array initially before the async actions return the data, so the code shouldn't error.

Comment: Yup. transactions.all doesnt have an initial state. (transactions: null) isn't the whole shape of the object. You can modify the initial state to (transaction: { all: [] }} or check if transactions is not null before proceeding to sort. You can do both ways.

Answer (score 1):

Managed to solve this, because in combine reducers, I had set transactions with the name `transactions` and then in the reducer, I essentially had the initial state set to `transactions: { all: [] } }`.

This was causing `state.transactions.all` to be undefined, as the correct state structure was actually `state.transactions.transactions.all`.

After updating the transactions reducer to:

```
const INITIAL_STATE = { all: [], transaction: null }

export default function (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) {
  switch (action.type) {...
```

The initial empty transactions array prior to the promise returning meant the sort no longer causes an error, and is then correctly sorted on load.